# Excel Macro to perform a formula where one column has the same value in several rows

Tags: excel, vba7

I can't quite find the right code example to do what I'm looking to do.
We have an excel file with data from a project where a request can have several TASKs associated with it and different teams or organizations can be assigned.   I'm trying to create a summary of whether the request was worked on by one team or another or "jointly" worked on (based on more than one team/org being assigned to tasks under the same request).
Here is the example and the result I'm looking for:

[image: Picture of spreadsheet data and results]

I want the code to be able to loop thru all rows checking where column A (request #) is the same value and builds an array of the value contained in column B (Team assigned) for each row where A has the same value. Then some sort of function to determine if the values in the array contain more than 1 team.  If all of the TASKs were worked on by one team, just that team is the result, if more than one team worked on TASKs, the it results with "Joint".

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with VBA? It can easily be achieved with a couple formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without VBA, using formulas.

For the Result column in my screenshot, column E, I used

```
=IF(COUNTIFS([request],[@request],[team],[@team])=COUNTIFS([request],[@request]),[@team],"Joint")
```

The same formula without structure references reads like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$22,B3,$c$3:$c$22,c3)=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$22,B3),E3,"Joint")
```

Apply the formula to the whole table column. If you don't want to use structured references, make sure to use absolute references for the column ranges, i.e. `$B$3:$B$22` etc.

The Pivot table has Request and Result in the row areas, and the Tasks in the Values area. A pivot table needs to be refreshed when new data is added.

A dynamic result table can be achieved with the new dynamic array formulas available in Office 365 versions of Excel.

In H12 and I12 of my screenshot I use

```
=UNIQUE(Table1[request])
=XLOOKUP(H12#,Table1[request],Table1[Result])
```

The formula automatically spills down as far as required.

So, no VBA required, which means you can save as a regular .xlsx file, which will also run perfectly fine in the browser and on mobile devices.

[image]

Comment: teylyn, thank you.  I was trying to get away with using formulas as well, but didn't think I could do it.   In your formula: =IF(COUNTIFS([request],[@request],[team],[@team])=COUNTIFS([request],[@request]),[@team],"Joint")  .... what is the [request] and [team] in the formula?  Named ranges?

Comment: These are structured references that you can use if your data is in an Excel Table (insert > Table). This has been around since Excel 2007, so only 15 years. As I also point out in my post, you can use regular references instead, but need to make sure they don't change when the formula is copied down, hence absolute references with $ signs for the ranges, not the comparison cell)

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I added a formula without structured references to my answer.